# Let $f$ on $[0,\infty)^d$ satisfy $f(tx) = t^{-d}f(x)$ for $t > 0$, $d \geq 1$. Does it follow that $f$ is not integrable on $[0,\infty)^d$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be positive, continuous, and defined on $[0,\infty)^d$ satisfying $f(tx) = t^{-d}f(x)$ for $t > 0$, with $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in [0,\infty)^d$,  $d \geq 1$. Does it follow that $f$ is not integrable on $[0,\infty)^d$?

I see that $\int_{[0,\infty)^d} f(y)dy = \int_{[0,\infty)^d} f(\frac{y}{t}t)dy = \int_{[0,\infty)^d} t^{-d} f(\frac{y}{t})dy = \int_{[0,\infty)^d} t^{-d+1} f(y)dy$, but I don't think that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are almost there.

Assume by way of contradiction that $\int_{[0,\infty)}f(x)dx = c >0$ as $f$ is positive.

Then you would have that for any $t>0$:

$$ c = \frac{c}{t^{d+1}} \iff t = 1 , \forall t > 0 $$

which is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, the argument should work for $d>1$, but seems like I made a typo and it should be integral over $t^{-d+1}$ so it won't work for $d = 1$

Comment: You are right it does not hold for d=1 and for any $d$, I took you calculation for granted, but there is a mistake at the change of variables. I will delete the answer and come back .

Answer (score 0):

For $d=1$, since $f$ is homogeneous of order $-1$, $f(x) = f(1x) =\frac{1}{x}f(1)$, and $f$ is clearly not integrable.